# Why are some characters get a pale highlight in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I noticed that sometimes characters in WebStorm get highlighted with a pale color, just as if there is something wrong with that character. But when hovering over that character, there is no hint or anything, the right-click menu does not show any special functionality, and there is no mentioning at the Inspection-bar at the right.

Here is an example (the ':' after 'clear') from an AngularJS source file:

[image]

What is WebStorm trying to tell me?

Comment: I think it's expecting a space after the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This light-green background indicates language injection (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/using-language-injections.html) - WebStorm auto-injects CSS in `style` attribute value. If you don't like its background color, you can change it in `Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General` (`Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General` since 2017.2), `Code / Injected language fragment` settings, *Background* .